# Javascript that makes every page better?

Tags: javascript, html, web, fixed, web-development-server

Has anyone stumbled upon or written any javascript code that can be included in practically any html page and serves to improve the site or add some functionality without interfering with the existing layout and logic? Open to any and all answers.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "better". A fun little bookmarklet is the one from http://fontbomb.ilex.ca/, but it does "interfere" with the layout of the page; a bit

Answer (score 1):

**CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)** is the answer for your problem.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS